# c# Multiple base classes

Tags: c#, oop, object-oriented-analysis, ooad

I'm having a little problem designing my classes.

What I want to do is the following:
There are 4 classes with each their own properties. A physical and mailing address can be national or international. The contact class should have two properties of some type where I can access all the needed properties.

I've tried to a create base classes for national/international and for physical/mailing but I'm struggeling with the fact they all have different properties.

How would you model the classes in a proper way? Is it even possible in c#? I'm afraid I'll just have to create 4 properties on Contact for each of the 4 classes and do a null check to see which type of adress the object has.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Contact c = new Contact();
    }
}

public class Contact
{
    public xxx PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
    public xxx MailingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class NationalAddress
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber Landline { get; set; }

    public string Street{ get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber{ get; set; }
    public string PostalCode{ get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
}

public class InternationalAddress
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } 
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber Landline { get; set; }

    public string AdresRule1 { get; set; }
    public string AdresRule2 { get; set; }
    public string AdresRule3 { get; set; }
}

public class PhysicalAddress
{        
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsVerified { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }

    //Semi-detached/Terraced/Appartment/...
    public TypeOfBuilding Building{ get; set; } 
    public bool Occupied { get; set; } 
}

public class MailingAddress
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsVerified { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }

    public bool AllowCommercialPress { get; set; }
    public bool AllowOfficialPress { get; set; }
}
```

Regards,

Miscode

Comment: Yes, you'll certainly have a problem when you cannot think of better property names than "X", "b", "Prop3".  Fix that first, come back later.

Comment: That is absolutely true! But of course those property names are not the real ones and are just added to give you a better idea of the dependencies between the classes. The 4 classes are having the same properties(X). The National/International and Physical/Mailing classes are having their properties, resp a and b. 
I could have put a real name(or even every 79 properties) but that would not make a difference to the solution.

Comment: My suggestion would be to take out one or two real properties instead of using "X", "b" etc. That would make your question a lot easier to read. Could you do that?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with more detailled properties.

Comment: Looks a lot better, I upvoted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1**

A different approach this time --> I refactored your original properties / classes a bit.

**AddressRule vs separate properties**

Why doesn't an InternationalAddress have a Street, HouseNumber, ... etc? I refactored this into a List which can have one entry for your NationalAddress and multiple entries for your InternationalAddress.

**Validation properties**

Why are these validation properties in the Physical / Mailing address? From what I can tell these should be in the highest level.

```
public class Contact
{
    public PhysicalAddress PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
    public MailingAddress MailingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class AddressRule
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class BaseAddress
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber Landline { get; set; }

    public List<AddressRule> AdressRules { get; set; }

    public bool IsVerified { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }
}

public class PhysicalAddress : BaseAddress
{        
    //Semi-detached/Terraced/Appartment/...
    public TypeOfBuilding Building { get; set; }
    public bool Occupied { get; set; }
}

public class MailingAddress : BaseAddress
{       
    public bool AllowCommercialPress { get; set; }
    public bool AllowOfficialPress { get; set; }
}
```

**Part 2**

If you really need a separate class for International and National I propose to create a property of type AddressBase in your Physical / Email class which. This AddressBase property can then be either International or National.

```
public class Contact
{
    public PhysicalAddress PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
    public MailingAddress MailingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class AddressBase
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber Landline { get; set; }
}

public class NationalAddress : AddressBase
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class InternationalAddress : AddressBase
{
    public string AdresRule1 { get; set; }
    public string AdresRule2 { get; set; }
    public string AdresRule3 { get; set; }
}


//I'm guessing Mailing and Physical is meant to know where to ship to, hence the "Transport" prefix.
public class TransportAddressBase
{
    **public AddressBase AddressBaseInformation{ get; set; }**

    public bool IsVerified { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }
}



public class PhysicalAddress : TransportAddressBase
{       
    //Semi-detached/Terraced/Appartment/...
    public TypeOfBuilding Building { get; set; }
    public bool Occupied { get; set; }
}

public class MailingAddress : TransportAddressBase
{       
    public bool AllowCommercialPress { get; set; }
    public bool AllowOfficialPress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! What type would you choose for the physical address property in the contact class? I think that if you choose the PhysicalAddress class you can't access the National/International properties.

Comment: Oh right. I'll edit it.

Comment: I'll blame the friday morning, but I still can't figure this one out :) 
In your example a physicalAddress can never be a NationalAddress as there is no inheritance between those classes?

Comment: Perhaps an extra addition to my question. With physicalAddress I mean the class PhysicalAddress and not the one in contact property. You must see national/international as abstract classes as they can never exist by themselves.

Comment: I'll edit my answer when I get back (gotta go for a few hours now). I'll try to clarify the abstraction you just mentioned.

Comment: I added 2 proposals. Can we chat somewhere if this still doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: Cool, I think you are confirming my thoughts that it can't be done with inheritance only ;) Somewhere in code you still need to check of which type the AddressBaseInformation is, but that is ok. Part1 is not possible for me as international en national address are from different db providers. International address are just strings without knowing what info is entered so they cannot be matched into a more typed set. You have helped me a lot, thnx!